# IE 10 - onbeforeunload - server side processing

Tags: javascript, ajax, onbeforeunload

Here's what I'm after.
When user clicks 'X' to close the IE 10 browser. Do the following:

1. Trap the `onbeforeunload` event in javascript
2. Make an ajax call to a server resource (a servlet) which has some logic to run and return a status
3. Based on the response popup a message on the page

The issue is that, it unloads the page, and I'm unable to make a servlet call.
I tried putting a delay in the javascript, still no luck.

Any help or workaround appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing user from closing a page **is not** possible and **should not** be possible. The reason is security and user experience.

Let's assume for a moment that user enters a malicious page that has hooked into [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event and that the browser would allow waiting for an ajax call, triggered from [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) handler, to complete. Waiting for the request to complete could take arbitrary amount of time - thus preventing user from closing the page.

Your only option to customise the exit is to return a pre-crafted message **synchronously** from within the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event handler.

Maybe it your case it would be possible to build the message ahead of time (potentially via ajax call to server) and store it in a way accessible from the mentioned event handler.

Comment: Agree, looks like a probable security vulnerability. 
I'm able to show a simple static message. Will need a think of a push mechanism, like you mentioned , whereby the message is pre-crafted and ready to be displayed on the client side.